# regex group results and or

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to return an array with two of the important regex checks?

Something like this - `/(?=.*\d days)(?=.*car|truck|motorcycle)/`

First problem is that the regex doesn't match car or other vehicles...
Second - is it possible to extract the number of days `...*\d days(...` into a separate array value?

At the moment my regex is - `/(?=.*\d days)(?=.*car)/`
and the response is - `[ '', index: 0, input: '5 days before cleaning the car' ]`
and i'm striving for - `[ '5', index: 0, input: '5 days before cleaning the car']`

Inputs

```
5 days before cleaning a car 
Motorcycle cleaning in 23 days 
truck will arrive in 10 days
```

Basically I want to get the number of days for any of the vehicles that might exist in a short text.

Comment: What does the input look like?!

Comment: Updated the question to include potential inputs and what I'm expecting to get.

Comment: And your goal is just to capture the number of days?

Comment: yes. I just want to extract that value...

Comment: Your expression is extremely close. I changed the `\d` to `([0-9]+)` this way it'll capture multiple digits. And I changed `car|truck|motorcycle` to `(car|truck|motorcycle)` so they would be captured... well technically the vehicle types can appear in any sequence, but to improve efficiency they should sorted from the most common to the least.  I then added a `.*` to the end so that capture group 0 would get the entire string... just incase you wanted it for further analysis elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Oh the `[0-9]` construct is slightly more efficient than `\d`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Description

```
^(?=.*?([0-9]+)\s*days)(?=.*?(motorcycle|truck|car)).*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regex will do the following:

- capture the number of days
- capture the type of vehicle

## Examples

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/qY5nL6/1

**Sample Text**

```
5 days before cleaning a car
Motorcycle cleaning in 23 days
truck will arrive in 10 days
```

**Sample Matches**

```
[0][0] = 5 days before cleaning a car
[0][1] = 5
[0][2] = car

[1][0] = Motorcycle cleaning in 23 days
[1][1] = 23
[1][2] = Motorcycle

[2][0] = truck will arrive in 10 days
[2][1] = 10
[2][2] = truck
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    days                     'days'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      motorcycle               'motorcycle'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      truck                    'truck'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      car                      'car'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Did you write that explanation and draw that image yourself or is there some helpful tool I don't know about that does that automatically?

Comment: WOW! Just WOW! What a great answer! Thanks for all the explanation! How did you do the graph btw? Can you suggest a good book on regex or resources that can help me learn it. It's such a fascinating skill to have!

Comment: I learned regular expressions from [regular-expression.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). The site is very detailed and explains exactly how the engine works. However it's not a simple easy read, plan on spending several days on each subpage.  About the diagram, I used [debuggex.com](http://www.debuggex.com). I'm not in any way affiliated with either site, other than a frequent user.

Comment: Thanks, man! Your answer is a great resource. I'll study it and explore the link that you posted. Awesome!